# rails ghost migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-migrations

I keep on getting duplicate devise migration files with the same name but different time stamp in my rails app. I thought the only way to create a migration is to do so manually. If so, why are these migrations being created?

Is it safe to simply delete one of these files?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you get them? I've never seen this.

Comment: I'm not even sure. I manage to restore the code to a point without the duplicates, save and commit. The next time I try to run a rake after some additional code I get the error "Multiple migrations have the name DeviseCreateAdmins"

Comment: You might have to include more information; I don't see why it would be creating migrations on its own. Obviously if the migrations are duplicates, and they've been run, there's no need to run them again.

Comment: Could have been created if you ran the generator twice perhaps?

Comment: Fairly certain I did not run the generator more than once. Unless there is a way to generate a migration without "generate" through cmd. Could be an issue with devise.

Comment: Come to think of it could be an issue with git somehow.